# Can't log into google apps after sim card change

Tags: google-account, connection-issues

I went to Germany and I had switch my PLAY (PL operator) SIM card with Blau.de SIM card. Everything was good, I had Internet connection and full facebook/twitter/google sync. After return to Poland, I switched to my original SIM card and my android phone failed to log into facebook/twitter/google.

I'm sure I'm using good passwords.
Error message says that phone was unable to establish Internet connection. But Internet is fully working (now I'm using my phone as a modem).
I have correct apn's and I can use for example gmail through default web browser.

I found in Internet that this is common problem with android phones, and it can be repaired after factory reset.

It's very important to me to avoid factory reset. Anyone know other way to log in?

My telephone: Samusng i5500, Android 2.1

Update:
I found that I can't fully use applications such as Waze, Glympse, Opera, basically all applications that use internet - they cannot connect to internet. But, I can use default browser to check gmail, and surf net. It looks like phone has disabled ability co connect to internet for every application except default web browser.

Update2: I can log into google account and fully sync phone when I'm using wifi. After disconnection from wifi everything is stopping despite the fact that I have GSM internet connection working.

**Solution: My operator has 3 different APN's, one for WAP, one for MMS and one for internet. First two was automatically configured, third one have to be added manually**

Comment: You're actually lucky -- my phone does a factory reset when I switch SIM cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd start by ensuring that the APN settings are correct.  A different SIM card from another carrier could have overwritten them.  You can access these by going to `Menu -> Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Mobile networks -> Access Point Names` and then tapping on the selected one to edit it.  The correct settings are sometimes listed on your carrier's website.  At worst you may need to call their support line.  While you are there, make sure under "Network Operators" option your provider is selected.  After making the changes toggle the Airplane mode on and off to re-connect to the mobile network.

Try dialing the following number in the Dialer app: `*#*#2432546#*#*` (spells out "checkin" between the stars and pounds) and see what it comes back with.

Comment: Thin number appears to be to long, or nothing come out from it because it vanish right after I type it in dial pad.

Comment: It's supposed to vanish - this is a special code that sends a "check-in" request to Google servers from your handset. A "checkin success" notification should appear if it worked.

Comment: OK, I tested this code on my wife telephone and I know what to expect. So on my telephone nothing appears.

Comment: As the post points out, first of all check the APN settings